# How to set RRSIG signature expiry validity manually (BIND9)

Tags: bind, dnssec

The default Resource record signature validity is 30 days of bind9 and we have to renew the signature validity by resigning the zone file every time. Otherwise the DNS resolver will unable to resolve the query from internet if the RR signature expired.
I am using bind 9.11.36 stable version in production.

1. Is there any way to extend the signature validity from 30 days to 1 year?
2. What is the industry best practice of setting up Resource record signature expiry duration for bind9 production environment?

Answer (score 1):

Just automate the signing. If you make this a manual, annual process, it is not guaranteed to work the next time you need it. People tend to forget how such things are done – or even that they exist and must be taken care of.

### Use Inline Signing

It has been over a decade since the *inline signing* was introduced with BIND 9.9 in 2012; all the versions not supporting it have already reached [EoL](https://kb.isc.org/docs/bind-9-end-of-life-dates). There are several tutorials on how to use it:

- Suzanne Goldlust (2019): [In-line Signing With NSEC3 in BIND 9.9+ -- A Walk-through](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00711)
- Suzanne Goldlust & Evan Hunt (2018): [Inline Signing in ISC BIND 9.9.0 -- Examples](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00626)
- Internet Systems Consortium, Inc.: DNSSEC Guide: [Chapter 4. Signing](https://dnsinstitute.com/documentation/dnssec-guide/ch04.html#signing-easy-start-reconfigure-bind)

You could even brew some coffee, relax on a sofa and enjoy a YouTube video on the subject:

- Internet Systems Consortium (2013): [BIND and Inline Signing](https://youtu.be/9Q3sCnXQ5vk) [46:11].

### Legacy solutions

Before BIND 9.9 there was only the `dnssec-keygen` & `dnssec-signzone` tools, and any automation involved running the `dnssec-signzone` in cronjobs or similar. In addition to the validity being 30 days the `-i` *interval* defaults to 7.5 days (`648000` seconds). The automated signing interval should be shorten than that, or the `-i` should be increased.

- SIDN: [DNSSEC signatures in BIND named](https://www.sidn.nl/en/modern-internet-standards/dnssec-signatures-in-bind-named); also covers the historical solutions

To answer your exact question, the [`dnssec-signzone(8)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/dnssec-signzone.8.html) has two options that controls the expiration of the RRSIG records. (A validity period of a year would be `-e +31556926`.)

> `-e end-time`
>
> This option specifies the date and time when the generated RRSIG
> records expire. As with  `start-time`,  an absolute time is indicated in
> `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` notation. A time relative to the start time is
> indicated with `+N`, which is N seconds from the  start time.  A  time
> relative to the current time is indicated with `now+N`. If no `end-time`
> is specified, 30 days from the start time is the default.  `end-time`
> must  be  later than `start-time`.
>
> `-X extended end-time`
>
> This  option  specifies  the date and time when the generated RRSIG
> records for the DNSKEY RRset expire. This is to be used in cases when
> the DNSKEY signatures need to persist  longer  than signatures on
> other records; e.g., when the private component of the KSK is kept
> offline and the KSK signature is to be refreshed manually.
>
> As with `end-time`, an absolute time is indicated in `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`
> notation. A  time relative  to the start time is indicated with `+N`,
> which is N seconds from the start time. A time relative to the current
> time is indicated with `now+N`. If  no  `extended end-time`  is specified,
> the value of `end-time` is used as the default. (end-time, in turn,
> defaults to 30 days from the start time.) `extended  end-time`  must  be
> later than `start-time`.

Comment: Hi Esa Jokinen,

Thanks for your reply..!

Could you please tell me the industry best practices related this auto signing process and configuration? Also, it would be a great help if you could share any documentation or article link for configuring this auto signing process in bind 9.11.36 version.

Comment: I've added some links to good tutorials as there's no use to write a new one. Evan Hunt is a [long-time](https://www.isc.org/bindhistory/) BIND 9 maintainer.